# Restoring code from a corrupt code file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, corrupt

My computer crashed while coding some C# in Visual Studio. After reinstalling the computer I still have the `.cs` file and it has the size of 9KB, but when I open it with for example Notepad, it's completely empty. Is there anyway I can restore the content somehow? I did some Google searches, but wasn't able to find anything helpful.

Comment: I'm sure you have some **backup** at hand, or you've checked in your source code into **source control** ? Just get it from there.....

Comment: If your file doesn't contain sensitive or proprietary code, could you upload it somewhere for us to check?

Comment: sometime with free undelete you can find an old version of the file in the directory http://www.officerecovery.com/freeundelete/.  Using source control is the best way to prevent losing a code file